# Bootstrap Grid [2 items] in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-grid

I'm making a website using bootstrap and this is a screenshot of the grid from w3schools.com. In my website, Instead of having my profile picture on the left **1 of 2** and a bullet list on the right side on **2 of 2**.

I want my profile picture on **2 of 4** and a bullet list on **3 of 4** while leaving **1 of 4** and **4 of 4** empty. Just basically having two items more in the centered of the page.

How can I accomplish this task?

[image]

Comment: How about an invisible `div` on those grids? just make a `<div>` with an items inside and set `display: hidden` in CSS?

Comment: @AegirAideron Hey that worked. Instead of doing display: hidden, I used class = "hidden" and this worked also just fine! Thank you for helping me out. After looking up on your set of example. Here is the resource where I found more information about display settings https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
      picture here    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
      bullets here   
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Similar answer to @Aegir Aideron. display hidden worked perfectly for me! Thanks for the tip! Also class = "hidden" works too!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) your columns: `offset-sm-3` is specifing leave 1 of 4 empty

Use

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-3">Picture</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Bullets</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use offset while creating the grid use offset class which will help you align your `col` in center :

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#offset-classes)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 ">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
</div>
```